# sort lines by regexp

Tags: regular-expressions, sorting

I have a todo list in a text file that I maintain with TaskAgent and emacs. TaskAgent adds trailing text to a line to indicate priority (#!!! represents highest, #! represents low, and no mark is lowest). I would like to sort the lines by priority in emacs from highest to lowest, for example:

```
groceries 
haircut #!!
water plants #!!!
clean gutters #!
```

would be sorted as

```
water plants #!!! 
haircut #!!
clean gutters #!
groceries
```

`(sort-regexp-fields t "^.*$" "#!+" (point-min) (point-max))`

almost works but ignores the lowest priority (non-marked) items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```el
(sort-regexp-fields t "^.*?\\(#!+\\|\\)$" "\\1" (point-min) (point-max))
```

Comment: Please do not make this a code-only answer.